# How can native Android and IOS applications use WebGL?

Tags: android, ios, webgl

Is it possible today for a native Android and IOS applications use WebGL?

It looks like  Android WebView and IOS UIWebView (except for iAd) do not support WebGL, correct?

What other libraries (not browsers) support WebGL on Android and IOS? It would be great to  have some examples.

Comment: You've probably found this already, but just in case http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/03/enabling-and-using-webgl-on-ios/ shows a recipe (hack) to use webgl on ios. Probably not app-store compliant.

Comment: What about Android? I am running Chrome on emulator and it gives the error message saying that WebGL is not supported. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Safari in iOS 8 now supports WebGL and Chrome in Android offers partial support. Unfortunately the stock Android browser does not yet offer support, though that appears to be coming. Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl

As you have mentioned, WebViews would be the way to go to utilise this new tech.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8 supports WebGL in the WebView, there are 2 WebViews available in iOS8, UIWebView and WKWebView, both supports WebGL that can be included in a native app. `WKWebView` has a faster JS engine which performs 2X-10X better than `UIWebView`

Android WebView does not support WebGL yet (atleast until v4.4.4), however you can use a custom WebView as part of the app to support WebGL, [Crosswalk runtime](http://crosswalk-project.org) can be used for a WebView in Android native app, which supports on Android 4.x versions and supports WebGL, WebAudio, WebRTC and more...